# .C# MVC Routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core

How can I create a custom route that will return a specific controller and action without having to type the controller and action in the URL? For example the URL would be [www.test.com/myuserid](http://www.test.com/myuserid). I also need a condition added so that if the {myuserid} value is not included in the URL the default route will return:

```
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will catch routes similar to /some-string and redirect to `HomeController`'s `Index` method. My code is for ASP.NET Core 3.1, but looks like you got v2.2, so you might have different methods for that, but arguments should be the same

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");


    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{id?}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
});
```